# Concurrent flow graph

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, system.reactive, tpl-dataflow

OK, bunch of informations:

### Scenario

- There is no UI.
- I need to do a lot of calculations on a server.
- As for now, the predicted time to finish them is a **month**.
- I need to parallelize the code, using the best techniques available. I can sacrifice a lot of time improving this.
- The synchronous part of the code is assumed to be written in an optimal way. The only possible way to improve the performance is to parallelize independent operations.

### Nature of the calculations

- Operations I need to perform form a **flow graph**. And edge represents an fully independent operation. In vertex `A` I start with only one task to do. When a task is being performed, it creates a bunch of other tasks to do. So in the very end I will have millions of tasks. Visualization:

[image]

- The vast majority of operations is really fast. They take like 100 milliseconds. Some of them, though, are longer. These are requests to external services.

A simple approach to just run all the operations asynchronously kills the machine - the overhead of creating millions of tasks is massive.

### Question

How should I approach this problem? `Parallel`? `PLINQ`? Rx? Dataflow? Something else? Thread pool directly?

Comment: Give an example of task. Instead of million of similar tasks you can have just one running a loop.

Comment: If this runs for a month on a single server you have other problems to worry about. Making it resilient to failures and being able to resume after a failure would be high on my list. Why does your scenario limit you to just one server?

Comment: @IanMercer That's true, but it will be covered later. As for the server - I'm using Azure. Money is the reason not to buy more resources :)

Comment: On Azure you pay per hour, so you could easily spin up extra capacity for a limited duration and then shut everything down once you are done. If you calculation really takes 30 days, your bug life cycle is going to be very long.

Answer (score 3):

A million TPL tasks are not directly a problem. This will consume a few hundred MB of memory. Probably, you have other data attached to those tasks that cause high memory consumption.

Also, the TPL is prone to spawn an unlimited number of threads over time. It has no idea how to properly schedule IO. The number of threads literally rises infinitely.

Whatever mechanism you use to schedule this work: It does not matter for total time elapsed. Scheduling and running a million no-op tasks is a matter of seconds.

You probably should to process the graph in custom scheduled order. My approach would be to schedule calls to external services first. That way the gaps can be filled with the quicker tasks that happen to be available.

The `TaskScheduler` abstraction is not suitable for this. It does not play well with IO.

Architecturally, I would make the scheduling decisions whenever a task ends. Then, you can decide according to a policy what to start next. For example, you might want to have as many CPU bound operations in flight as there are CPU core. And you might want to have N IO operations outstanding at any time.